# text reverting from custom to web-safe font when reloading(override cache)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I changed my font to Arial, but set my header fonts to a custom font. I put my fonts in a folder called MYFONT, which is in a folder called fonts, which is in my root directory. (root directory -> fonts -> MYFONT -> font files) Here is my code:

```
CSS
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MYFONT';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-display: optional;
    src: url(fonts/MYFONT/MYFONT.woff2) format('woff2'),
         url(fonts/MYFONT/MYFONT.woff) format('woff'),
         url(fonts/MYFONT/MYFONT.svg) format('svg'),
         url(fonts/MYFONT/MYFONT.eot) format('eot');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'MYFONT', sans-serif;
}
```

```
HTML
<h1>MYFONT</h1>
<h2>MYFONT</h2>
<h3>MYFONT</h4>
<p>ARIAL</p>
```

When I first open the page on a new device, or when I press Cmd + Shift + R (reload page without browser cache) the entire page is in Arial. What could be the problem? I want the `<h1>, <h2>, and <h3>` to be use the MYFONT font.

**EDIT:
I tried removing the "`sans-serif`" part in

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'MYFONT', sans-serif;
}
```

and on first load/loading without cache the font turned into the default serif font.**

Comment: You can use !important in h1,h2,h3 tag

Comment: What happens if you merely add `font-style: normal;` to the h1,h2,h3 definition as well?

Comment: what  do you mean

Comment: @DuncanLeung Right now, you have `h1, h2, h3 {font-family: 'MYFONT', sans-serif;}`. have you tried telling css to always choose the normal weight from the font, as in my comment above? Alternately, you could set up a jsfiddle with an absolute link to the font (i.e. google fonts API). That way we can safely dicker with your code.

Comment: remove those `svg` and `eot` sources (svg hasn't been a valid format for years, and eot became a dead format when MS killed off IE8, more than 3 years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it, apparently, it was the problem of `font-display: optional;`, I changed it to `font-display: swap;` and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a `@font-face` rule at a specific weight, then you font is only going to kick in *at that weight*. So either remove `font-weigth: 600` from your font face declaration, or add `font-weight: 600` to your `h1,h2,h3` rule. `@font-face` is for loading specific font assets for specific family/style/weight combinations, and the more specific the font face declaration, the more specific your regular CSS will have to be in order for the font-face rule to kick in, too.

Comment: my problem is not the font weight, it is the font itself.

Comment: Cool: take this on board anyway. If you suspect it's the font, the obvious course of action is to first get a fresh copy of the font from a source you know is good (and, to remember to include `format("woff")`/`format("woff2")` for your two sources - only add woff/woff2, don't add anything else. No svg, eot, ttf, or otf).

Comment: @DuncanLeung This question seems like a good lesson in code troubleshooting. Note that what happened here was: 1. A/B test on `font-style` (nope), 2. A/B test on `font-weight` (nope), 3. A/B test on `font-display` (Bingo! Problem solved.) Nice and orderly!